# Objective-C Sort NSMutableArray of Objects by a specific Object attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an object called Station in my system with these attributes:

```
@interface Station : NSObject {
NSString *stationID;
NSString *callsign;
NSString *stationState;
}
```

I also have an NSMutableArray containing 20 'Station' objects as defined above.

I need to define a method which can can sort this array in 2 ways:
1) By stationID
2) By callsign

Can someone please explain how I can do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use

```
NSInteger stationsSort( Station *station1, Station *station2, void *context) {
    if ( station1_greater_than_station2 )   {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ( station1_less_than_station2 ) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return NSOrderedSame;   
}

[myArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:stationsSort context:nil];
```

Comment: I would recommend return signature is NSComparisionResult

Comment: vodkhang, I agree, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at NSPredicates. This can be used for query and sorting objects in Arrays.

Examples are here as well.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

And NSSortDescriptor - With examples.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html